# Binding crystal report with multi custom table from one dataset only show 1 row

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, crystal-reports

I'm dealing with an issue with the crystal report. What I want is binding my report with multi custom table (I create by my-self not same as table in database) from one dataset but if only work when I only drag and drop those fields in one table, when I drag and drop more than one table to the Details section, nothing be showed. So can you show me how to solve it or any good approach to solve my case?
Here is my code in aspx page:

```
 Reports.CompanyFundUsage.FundUsageDataSet ds = new Reports.CompanyFundUsage.FundUsageDataSet();

        var datarow = ds.Tables["TAISAN"].NewRow();
        double a = 123;
        datarow[0] = (float)a;
        datarow[1] = (float)a;
        datarow[2] = (float)a;
        ds.TAISAN.Rows.Add(datarow);
        ds.TAISAN.AcceptChanges();

        var row = ds.Tables["TIENMAT"].NewRow();
        row[0] = (float)a;
        row[1] = (float)a;
        row[2] = (float)a;
        ds.TIENMAT.Rows.Add(row);
        ds.TIENMAT.AcceptChanges();
        ds.AcceptChanges();
        string path = Server.MapPath("/Reports/CompanyFundUsage/CompanyFundsReport.rpt");
        crystalReport.Load(path);
        crystalReport.SetDataSource(ds);
```

Comment: Is there any link between tables?

Comment: I've already delete all link, all of my datatable created by my-self so It doesn't have any constraint and so on